# Function currying in Haskell

Tags: haskell, currying, partial-application

I have a function:

```
powerOf :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

example os usage:

```
*Main Data.List> powerOf 100 2
2
*Main Data.List> powerOf 100 5
2
```

I have two questions. First - why it doesn't works:

```
map (powerOf 100) [2, 5]
```

I want to get [2, 2].

And second question.  I trying to create pariatl function. Something like this:

```
powerOfN :: Int -> Int
powerOfN num = powerOf num
```

to use it such way:

```
let powerOf100 = powerOfN 100
powerOf100 2
powerOf100 5
```

but i got the error message:

```
simplifier.hs:31:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int'
           against inferred type `Int -> Int'
    In the expression: powerOf num
    In the definition of `powerOfN': powerOfN num = powerOf num
```

Here is full of may code:

```
divided :: Int -> Int -> Bool
divided a b = 
  let x = fromIntegral a
      y = fromIntegral b
  in (a == truncate (x / y) * b)

listOfDividers :: Int -> [Int]
listOfDividers num =
               let n = fromIntegral num
                   maxN = truncate (sqrt n)
               in [n | n <- [1.. maxN], divided num n]


isItSimple :: Int -> Bool
isItSimple num = length(listOfDividers num) == 1

listOfSimpleDividers :: Int -> [Int]
listOfSimpleDividers num = [n | n <- listOfAllDividers, isItSimple n]
                     where listOfAllDividers = listOfDividers num

powerOfInner :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
powerOfInner num p power
             | divided num p = powerOfInner (quot num p) p (power + 1)
             | otherwise = power

powerOf :: Int -> Int -> Int
powerOf num p = powerOfInner num p 0


powerOfN :: Int -> Int
powerOfN num = powerOf num
```

powerOf return maximum power of p in num. For example: 100 = 2 * 2 * 5 *5, so powerOf 100 2 = 2. 10 = 2 * 5, so powerOf 10 2 = 1.

How to fix errors? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the code for `powerOf`?

Comment: `powerOf` seems to be broken or misnamed. 100 to the power of 2 is 10000 as far as I know.

Comment: I post all my code and explain powerOf.

Comment: It still works just fine — http://ideone.com/2fOdW

Comment: It was my mistake. I'm trying map (powerOf 100) [1, 2, 5] and got unfinite recursion. http://ideone.com/kuGVM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your code, apart from the powerOfN function. I cannot reproduce your problem with `map (powerOf 100) [2,5]`.

```
*Main> map (powerOf 100) [2,5]
[2,2]
```

Do you get any sort of error?

---

Regarding your second problem:

```
powerOfN :: Int -> Int
powerOfN num = powerOf num
```

The type signature is incorrect.

powerOfN takes an integer and returns a function that takes an integer and returns an integer.

So the type signature should be

```
powerOfN :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

Which is the same as (Thanks to [delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395760/delnan) for confirming it):

```
powerOfN :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

Comment: It's not even necessary, `powerOfN 100` is the same as `powerOf 100`.

Comment: @Piotr: Exactly, that's the whole point of implicit currying/making n-ary function unary function returning (n-1)-ary functions.

Comment: Yes, than you. It was my mistake. I'm trying map (powerOf 100) [1, 2, 5] and got unfinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your confusion.  You want a version of "powerOf" that takes a single argument, so you tried to define "powerOfN" which only takes one argument.  But in fact "powerOf" already does that.  You have to read "->" as a type operator.  Just as "+" is an operator on numbers, so "->" is an operator on types; it takes two types and returns a new one.  So

```
Foo -> Bar
```

is a function from a "Foo" to a "Bar".  But since this is a type, you can apply another "->" operation to it, like this:

```
Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

which means a function that takes an Int, and returns a new function that takes a second Int and returns an Int as the result.

Haskell defines the "->" operator to be right associative, so the brackets in this case can be dropped, so it looks like this:

```
Int -> Int -> Int
```

Which is the type of your "powerOf" function.  So you can use "powerOf" and give it one argument, and what you get back is a new function that expects the second argument.  Which is what you wanted.